# Azure DevOps Repository References at compile time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to base some compile time logic off one of the repository references branches, but to get this reference I need to get it at runtime:

```
variables:
  - name: refBranch
    value: $[ resources.repositories['MyRepo'].ref ]
```

However, my logic is using the compile time syntax:

```
  - template: templates/my-template.yml
    parameters:
      variationNuspecs: 
        - ${{ if eq( variables['refBranch'], 'refs/heads/demo') }}:
          - code: 'demo'
        - ${{ else }}:
          - code: 'main'
```

This results in the `refBranch` variable at compile time being empty.

Does anyone know how I can either access the repository reference at compile time or how I an run my logic at runtime?